# How can I convert Firestore field data into auto-incrementing arrays?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using the following code to upload data entered in each of the fields into Firestore.

```
db.collection("users").getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print(error)
                    return
                } else {
                    for document in snapshot!.documents {
                        let data = document.data()
                        let userId = data["uid"] as! String
                        if userId == user?.uid {
                            document.reference.updateData(["productNameField":productname, "productURLField":producturl,"productPriceField":pricefield, "productDescriptionField":proddesc, "productTimeRemainingField":timeleft])
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

However once the data is uploaded onto my Firebase hosted database, each of the data fields are uploaded as separate strings, resulting in them being separate, as shown below.

[image]

How can I order and upload each dataset as an array, with automatically incrementing "product1", "product2" etc. name values?

Comment: Can you help clarify what your desired end result is? Is it that you want a dictionary of products keyed off off the product name or an array of products that automatically increment? Are the products meant to increment and be stored across multiple documents?

Comment: My desired end result is that once the form is submitted, each of the data fields entries will be stored in the database as an array in the same collection as each of the individual datasets currently reside in (shown in the image). If the same user then fills out the form again, then it would save this data as another array but with an incremented value (product1, product2, product3 etc.) does that clarify? The products are meant to be stored with the current users information, and only accessible by the current user logged in if that makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing built in for this in Firestore, so you will have to roll your own.

A simple way is to keep a field `entryCount` in the document, where you store the index of the last entry you've added to that document. Then when you add a new entry, you:

1. Read the current value of `entryCount`
2. Increment it by 1, and put that back into the document
3. Add the new field(s) with the updated count
4. Write the updated document back into the database

Comment: Ah ok thank you, I'll take a look into that. In the meantime, do you know how I'd be able to post the above form data into the database as a single array - instead of as multiple fields?

Answer (score 0):

If you choose to keep the products array within the same document as the user, I'd actually recommend against keeping an additional field with the count in the same document. My reasoning is that since you're already reading the document, you can just directly access the products array, get the count, and increment the name value accordingly. This allows for a single source of truth instead of having to maintain the `entryCount` field (i.e., handling cases where the user deletes the product) and risk it getting out of sync with the actual product array's length.

HOWEVER, I would recommend looking into using subcollections instead of maintaining an array within the same document for what you're trying to go for. If you go the subcollections route, then I **would** recommend tracking the `entryCount` in an additional field on the user document. It will save you extra reads and is worth the hassle of maintaining (this is also common practice with firestore). You can read about [firestore subcollections here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model). The benefit of using subcollections aside from keeping the user document focused is that storing the products as individual documents in a subcollection will not face the same document size restriction the array approach would have. You can also query subcollections.

To update the form data as a single array vs. multiple fields, you can do the following:

```html
let productDict = [
  "productDescriptionField": "test",
  "productNameField": "test",
  "productPriceField": "test",
  "productTimeRemainingField: "test",
  "productURLField: "Test"
]

document.reference.updateData([
  "products": FieldValue.arrayUnion(productDict)
])
```

[Reference for FieldValue.arrayUnion()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue)

To clean up the code further, you can declare the product as a struct and then use `product.dictionary` to update the document.

```html
struct Product {
  let description: String
  let name: String
  let price: String
  let timeRemaining: String
  let productURL: String
  
  var dictionary: [String: Any] {
    "description": description,
    "name": name,
    "price": price,
    "timeRemaining": timeRemaining,
    "productURL": productURL
  }
}
```

Finally, if you want to ensure that the currently logged-in user is the only one who can write to the document, I recommend looking into Cloud Firestore rules which will restrict who can write/read/update the document: [firestore rules docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started).